# Box2d for Qt 4.7

Tags: qt4, box2d

I am using Qt4.7. I was able to build Box2d for Visual Studio. But how can I use the header & library files of the Box2d in Qt  project.?

Comment: can you, pls, be more specific on what is the problem you're trying to solve. Once you got bax2d compiled in VS you can use it in your QT projects.

Comment: yes I have done with the compiling of Box2d in Visual Studio but how do I use that now for Qt projects?? How to add the libraries & header files??

Comment: can you describe your build system, do you use the visual studio add-in, qmake or perhaps cmake. Without this information, it's impossible to anwser your question accurately

Answer (score 1):

To add header file directory to your Project:
 1. Right click on the project in the 'Solution Explorer' and select 'Properties'
 2. Click 'C/C++'
 3. Give the directory you want to include in the 'Additional Include Directories' - box, separate it from the others with a semicolon
 4. Click Ok

To add library files to your Project:
 1. Right click on the project in the 'Solution Explorer' and select 'Properties'
 2. Click 'Linker'
 3. Insert the custom import libraries into the 'Additional dependencies' Box, Note that if your paths contain spaces, you must use Quotations around the path. This is because the list is separated with spaces.
 4. Click Ok

I don't remember if Box2d is a static or dll library, but in either case you need the .lib file. Unless you load it run-time, which I doubt.

If you want to know why, JGI!